# Facebook API for the siderbar feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find the FB Graph API request to get the feed on that sidebar which BTW I really don't know the name of it and that would help a lot to google it.

So, the questions are:
1 - Is there any graph request for that?
2 - What's the name of that sidebar?

I'm attaching a picture just to be sure.!

[image: facebook sidebar]

Comment: Well now I know that the name is 'News Ticker'. But there's no way to request that feed from the graph api.